# Oracle ODAC 18.3 for Windows Server 2019 Installation Errors

Tags: windows, oracle, server, odac

I am trying to install Oracle ODAC 18.3 on a Windows Server 2019 Standard so that I can create a data source connection to an Oracle database from a SQL Server 2019 instance, either by using Polybase or a Linked Server connection. The only components that I need installed are the Oracle Provider for OLE DB and Oracle Provider for OLE DB for OLAP. During the Perform Prerequisite Checks stage of the install, there are errors.

The errors are as follows:

> PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\CVU_18.0.0.0.0_[username]\ on nodes ""
>   Please select a different work area for the framework
>   [hostname] : PRKN-1014 : Failed to execute remote command "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\CVU_18.0.0.0.0_[username]\\exectask.exe" on node "[hostname]". Failed during connecting to service
>   [hostname] : Failed during connecting to service

Notes regarding error message above. [username] refers to my username that I am logging in with to Windows. It is an Active Directory account. [hostname] refers to the computer name that I am trying to install ODAC on. Also, I have tried installing this a few different times, all with the same error messages. On the second and third time installing I verified that during the installation the 
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\CVU_18.0.0.0.0_[username]\ directory is getting created, so this should not be a permissions issue.

In the PRKN-1014 error message, I did notice that there is an extra backslash in the path, CVU_18.0.0.0.0_\[username]\\exectask.exe, so my suspicion is that there is an issue with the installer not being able to identify the correct path to find the exectask.exe. If I traverse to the 
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\CVU_18.0.0.0.0_[username]\ directory I indeed find the exectask.exe file.

I have found a few different solutions online for others that worked for them, but none have worked for me. One solution was to add in the System Environment Variables the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable with a value of -Xmx512M. A second solution was to change the Environment Variables user variables TEMP and TMP to C:\TEMP. Neither of these worked and resulted in the exact same errors. I did in fact confirm that the Oracle Universal Installer extracted the files to the C:\TEMP directory.

Any and all suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Having the same issue as described here, but on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the Oracle "Universal" Installer to work, like you.  However, I was able to install the Oracle Provider for OLE DB and Oracle Provider for OLE DB for OLAP (same as you were trying to get) using the ODAC Xcopy installer.

I downloaded the ODAC Xcopy installer from here:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html

After downloading the installer, I ran the install batch file to install those two components.  An extra undocumented step is that you must update the PATH environment variable on your system to include your install location and bin folder.  In my case, "C:\Oracle" and "C:\Oracle\Bin".